# move data from old hard drives to pc via usb

Tags: backup

I have a bunch of old hard drives  from old pc's, and I would like to move data from it to my computer. I figure there must be a usb connectors to do that. Would you recommend where to get it and how to use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have [**this SATA/IDE to USB adapter**](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=2477926&CatId=3770). Works great for this kind of thing since it fits old IDE drives as well as SATA drives and you don't need to open up your computer - $20.

[image]

Comment: These are awesome

Comment: It really is a great resource to have, external hard drives can be expensive.

Comment: Don't know how I ever lived without mine. Every now & then I'll clone my C:\ drive to a spare sitting in the desk drawer. Waiting for that day when my main drive dies, since it's almost 4 years old and has a lot of hours on it.

Comment: +1 same thing i'd recommend.  if that's the same as mine it also fits 2.5" IDE drives (laptop-style) which is extremely handy.

Comment: +10 ordered it on amazon though. Do you get commission?